# parse_url returning empty string for url: 'www.example.com'

Tags: php, url

Why is parse_url returning empty string in this case?

```
<?php
$url='www.example.com';
$var= parse_url($url,PHP_URL_HOST);
print_r($var);
```

Comment: Try adding http at the front of the URL?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The string is interpreted as *relative URL*:

```
// print_r(parse_url('www.vtechpcsupport.com'))
Array
(
    [path] => www.vtechpcsupport.com
)
```

Comment: Yep, but the weird thing is that [`parse_url`](http://php.net/parse_url#refsect1-function.parse-url-notes) documentation states: "This function doesn't work with relative URLs." Looks like this isn't  "seriously malformed URL" ;)

Comment: It also says "Partial URLs are also accepted, parse_url() tries its best to parse them correctly."

Comment: @Juicy: Mmh. Maybe it is smarter than it claims. If I try `www.vtechpcsupport.com?foo=bar` it correctly identifiers `foo=bar` as query string.

Comment: @FelixKling, the documentation is a bit controversing, it claims "parsing URLs and not URIs" (with some "modifications") and have link to [RFC 3986](http://www.faqs.org/rfcs/rfc3986.html) which is "URI Generic Syntax"

Answer (score 2):

This is due to fact that `www.vtechpcsupport.com` isn't really a URL since it missing the `scheme` part (`HTTP` or so), try it like this:

```
$url = 'http://www.vtechpcsupport.com';
$var = parse_url($url,PHP_URL_HOST);
print($var);
```

Comment: It’s a URL but not one with a host.

Comment: @Gumbo, it't really not ;) [General URL Syntax](http://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc1738#section-2)

Comment: @Gumbo: just because browsers default to http for bare hostnames doesn't make it a url - a scheme is required for a proper url. e.g. what if that was actually 'ftp.vtechpcsupport.com' and didn't have a web server running on it?

Answer (score 1):

This is because www.vtechpcsupport.com is not a complete URL.

You are specifying PHP_URL_HOST so the function tries to extract just the host part of the URL, which doesn't exist as without a protocol being given the URL is treated as being relative -- so what you want to be the host name is interpreted as a (relative) path.

Try using:

```
$url='http://www.vtechpcsupport.com';
```

and you should get the behaviour you expect.